# Getting highest whole number of field in a database with an SQL Statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database filled with items each item has a version for example (1.0, 2.10, 3.22). These items can be edited. Every time an item gets changed they went up from 1.0 to 1.01. When the administrator accepts the changes of an item the version becomes 2.0 (a round up whole number).

So when there are a few changes made there can be multiple items with the same name but the content changes.

Is this a good way to 'version control information' / 'history system' and if so how do I create the SQL query to only show the latest final version example not 2.01, 2.07, 2.10 but only 3.0? the version field is a decimal (10,2).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, MAX(version)) AS StableVersion FROM versionsetc
```

Would that do the job for you?
Offcourse you'd have to change the column name and the table name.
Max gives you the highest number in that exact column.
Offcourse you are also able to select more columns if you'd like to by adding columns in the select clause after the max function.

Editted the query for you

Comment: If there is a 2.01, 2.10 but I only want a stable version so in this case 2.00. I think your query picks 2.10 not 2.00.

Comment: Okay changed up the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Select the max value and get the value of floor. This way 2.x will be 2.

```
SELECT name, FLOOR(MAX(version)) AS finalversion FROM items
```

Comment: This query does get the right version but It doesn't match with the right element. SELECT `name`, FLOOR(MAX(`version`)) AS finalversion FROM `items`. I get the first item of the tabel instead of 597.